# Creating a textfield using a button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an app that users can input random decisions and the app randomly chooses a decision. I just wanted to know how can I make a button add a new text filed for the user to write in, in case they want more than two decisions. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: You need a stackview and everytime the user clicks a button create a textfield, set it up and add it to the stackview.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one textfield, create it normally and set `textField.alpha = 0`. When the button pressed, just set it `textField.alpha = 1`. If you setup your  constraints well, it will look good.

Comment: What if I want to give the user the option to add as much text fields as they like?

Comment: Then use Rakesha’s answer:)

Comment: Yes, stackView is the best solution for what you want to achieve, because it already has its constraints, and when you add a textField inside, it will be placed nicely.